# Angular Logout won't clear local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

So here is my logout on ng-click: (my view)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default"><div class="container">
<div id="navbar-main">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-show="navvm.isLoggedIn" ng-hide="navvm.logout"><a href="profile">{{ navvm.currentUser.name }}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li ng-hide="navvm.isLoggedIn"><a href="login">Sign in</a></li>
    <li ng-show="navvm.isLoggedIn"><a ng-click="logOut()" href="">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then i'm trying to remove the localStorage by removing the token like so: (controller)

```
(function () {
  angular
   .module('meanApp')
   .controller('logoutCtrl', logoutCtrl);

     logoutCtrl.$inject = ['$location', '$window'];
     function logoutCtrl($location, $window) {
       logout = function() {
         $window.localStorage.removeItem('mean-token');
       };
     }
})();
```

(controller):

```
(function () {

  angular.module('meanApp', ['ngRoute']);

  function config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/home/home.view.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: '/auth/register/register.view.html',
        controller: 'registerCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/auth/login/login.view.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: '/profile/profile.view.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/logout', {
        templateUrl: '/home/home.view.html',
        controller: 'logoutCtrl',
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }

  function run($rootScope, $location, authentication) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
  if ($location.path() === '/profile' && !authentication.isLoggedIn()) {
    $location.path('/');
      }
    });
  }

  angular
    .module('meanApp')
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'authentication', run]);

})();
```

Whenever I try to logout the localStorage is still defined.  I've tried clearing the storage.  Tried deleting it.  Maybe i'm not doing the angular right.  I'm new to all of this so please help.  Thank you!

Comment: did you add a breakpoint or a console.log to make sure the logout code is being run?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the `$scope` variable into your controller and define logout function on the `$scope`

```
     logoutCtrl.$inject = ['$location', '$window', '$scope'];//injecting the $scope

     function logoutCtrl($location, $window, $scope) {

         //defining logout function on the $scope
         $scope.logout = function() {
             $window.localStorage.removeItem('mean-token');
         };

     }
```

Also you have a typo. Remove the 'O' uppercase on `logOut()`

```
<a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a>
```

Comment: well that makes sense.  I tried injecting the scope and the local storage still shows as defined.  I have no idea what to do to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Try without window.

`localStorage.removeItem('mean-token');`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Saninn/gf1oe2da/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to see? I have used `localStorage` in this way without problems. With a fiddle will be easier to help you.

Comment: Look at my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move logout function to homeCtrl, to check if it works there?